# Как пропарсить http запрос на ruby сервере?

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby

Я делаю ajax запрос на свой сервер. Получить запрос я могу, ответ с сервера также приходит. Но я не могу получить данные, которые я передаю по запросу. Как мне реализовать чтение данных?
Мой запрос

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5678/',
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
data:JSON.stringify({"cmd":"register","player":{"login":login,"pass":"","temp":1}})
})
```

Серверная часть

```
while session = server.accept
  request = session.gets
  puts request.data
  
  # 1
  method, full_path = request.split(' ')
  # 2
  path, query = full_path.split('?')
  puts query
  puts path
  puts method 
  
  session.print "HTTP/1.1 200\r\n" # 1
  session.print "Content-Type: text/html\r\n" # 2
  session.print "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n" # 3
  session.print "\r\n" # 3
  session.print "Hello world! The time is #{Time.now}" #4

  session.close
end
```

Comment: У вас сервер чисто на сокетах (TCP), значит нужно дописать разбор запроса, выдергивая отправленные данные или найти библиотеку, которая поможет работать с вебсерверами. Погуглив нашел такую https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra и пример обработки POST json https://willschenk.com/articles/2015/receiving-posted-json-with-sinatra/

Comment: У меня нет боди в реквест

Comment: @gil9red у меня нет body в request. И я не знаю как его взять

Comment: Хмм.. посмотрите пример с `data = JSON.parse request.body.read` (https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra#accessing-the-request-object) . И еще, возможно, лучше в ajax указывать `contentType: "application/json"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь передать данные по HTTP, а принять через TCP-сокет, но при этом запрашиваете `request.body` которого на уровне сокетов не существует, потому что это опция HTTP. Вам нужно определиться:

1. Хотите гонять байты по сокетам, тогда и передавайте их в сокет.
2. Хотите получать AJAX-запрос, тогда вам нужно принимать данные через HTTP.

Если вы пробуете урок вроде [этого](https://blog.appsignal.com/2016/11/23/ruby-magic-building-a-30-line-http-server-in-ruby.html), тогда вам нужно дополнительно реализовывать парсинг данных из сокета и в конечном итоге вы напишите свой HTTP, что довольно бессмысленно, потому что есть с десяток готовых библиотек.

Как это обычно делают:

Сначала ставите `sinatra`: `gem install sinatra`, затем создаете файл `server.rb`, вставляете в него код:

```rb
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'

post '/' do
  pp params
  "OK"
end

get '/' do
  erb :client
end
```

Затем создаете HTML-страничку `views/client.html` со следующим содержимым:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Client</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="ajax" type="button">Send AJAX-request</button>
    <script>
      var data = {
        cmd:'register',
        player:{
          login:'login',
          pass: '',
          temp:1
        }
      };
      var button = document.body.querySelector('#ajax');
          button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            $.ajax({
              url: 'http://127.0.0.1:4567/',
              method: 'POST',
              dataType: 'json',
              data: data
            })
          });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Запускаете `ruby server.rb`, заходите браузером на `http://127.0.0.1:4567/` и нажимаете кнопку. В консоли будет выведено что-то вроде этого:

```
::1 - - [18/Sep/2020:05:18:23 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 645 0.0101
{"cmd"=>"register", "player"=>{"login"=>"login", "pass"=>"", "temp"=>"1"}}
```